# Does Azure DevOps Services support tenant restrictions?

Tags: azure, azure-devops

We've been told by Microsoft support that Azure DevOps Services supports tenant restrictions. While we have tenant restrictions enabled on a number of other services, it does't seem to apply to DevOps. Not only can we still log in to organizations outside of our tenant, we can also log in to our own organization and, if our corp email is added as a user in that org, the organization also shows up. I'd expect that our users would be blocked from logging into or accessing any external orgs.

I'm a little confused about why this isn't just working as expected and despite them saying Azure DevOps Services supports tenant restrictions, I'm not finding much documentation to back that up.

Have you been able to migrate to Azure DevOps Services and ensure that your users are only able to access orgs within your own tenant? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We finally received a more concrete answer to this question from Premier Support. Sounds like this wasn't entirely clear internally either. Azure DevOps Services supports TRv1 which provides tenant restrictions from client to proxy, but does not support TRv2 tenant restrictions which provides server to server restrictions. TRv1 will prevent you from authenticating against an org outside your tenant directly but does nothing to prevent the background authentication that happens if your account is configured to be able to access a secondary tenant's org. The server to server connection strips off the header information necessary to restrict you from accessing the secondary tenant. While this feature may be on their radar there is no expectation or firm timeline for it's release at this time.

Answer (score 1):

Azure DevOps Service supports the Azure Active Directory (Azure AD) tenant policy to **restrict users from creating an organization in Azure DevOps**. This policy is turned off, by default. You must be an Azure DevOps Administrator in Azure AD to manage this policy.

[image]

[image]

Check following link for more details:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/azure-ad-tenant-policy-restrict-org-creation?view=azure-devops

> **Notice**:
>
> This policy is supported only for company owned (Azure Active
>   Directory) organizations. Users creating organization using their
>   personal account (MSA or GitHub) have no restrictions.
>
> https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/policy-support-to-restrict-creating-new-azure-devops-organizations/

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I'm aware of those restrictions. The problem though is that we can use tenant restrictions to prevent users from directly logging in with their personal account, but if they add their corp AD account to their own personal org, then log in with their corp AD account to our org, they also see and can interact (push code to git, etc) with their personal org.

Is there some configuration that permits us to lock down our Azure DevOps org so that it can only be accessed internally with a corp AD account while blocking our users from accessing any other org?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no such restriction. If you really want to have this restriction, you may submit a suggestion at website below: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21

Comment: Thank you for confirmation and the suggestion. We submitted the following suggestion: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/1079133/azure-devops-tenant-restrictions.html

Comment: Your answer is useful in that it helps confirm that this is not supported, but the one I marked above helps explain the distinction between how tenant restrictions work in some services vs others. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please accept your own reply as answer once you can:-).